# can zera still make clothes and objects tamei?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

In our generation, can clothes and objects still become tamei through zera? If so how do you get rid of the tumah?

Comment: see bartenura on kelim 1:1

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119510/759

Answer (score 4):

Yes, semen is still Tamei (Av HaTumah) and a lentil's worth of it would make other things Tamei (Velad HaTumah) through contact. You can remove this Tumah by dipping the clothing in the Mikvah. Why you would care to do so is not clear to me.

Comment: +1, you're undoubtedly correct, but citing a source would improve your answer.

Comment: Because i do not want to walk around with clothings that are tame. If you touch clothing do you become tamei?

Comment: @DovidBenizri Clothing that became Tamei from semen would not make you Tamei from touching it (Deoraita, at least). However, if anyone who has ever been in a cemetery touches the clothing after the Mikva then the clothing becomes Tamei again anyway. Also, why do you not want to walk around with clothing that is Tamei? Who cares?

Comment: Because I don't think it's the right thing to daven and to learn in tamei clothes

Comment: @dovid OK. Is that a Judaism thing or just a personal idiosyncracy?

Comment: What do you mean. Tumah distances you from abishter

Comment: @dovid I'm not entirely sure what that even means, but it's hard to imagine why the status of the clothing you are wearing would affect anything.