# Can mikvah water become tamei?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath

Can mikvah water ever become tamei from people's immersion? How does this relate to the essentially "living" quality of the water moving through the mikvah?

Related:

[using a men's mikvah twice if tamei or just once?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44846/using-a-mens-mikvah-twice-if-tamei-or-just-once)

[can zera still make clothes and objects tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44735/can-zera-still-make-clothes-and-objects-tamei)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Water in a Mikvah does not become Tamei. (Actually, Tamei water is the only food/drink which can become Tahor again, and this is by connecting it to a Mikvah (Mishna, Beitza 2:3).)

See the first chapter of Mishna Mikvaot (with commentaries) for more about exactly when a collection of water gains this property.

Answer (score 1):

No, a mikve remains pure, as written in vayikra 11, 36 .

Mikve water is considered 'connected to the ground', and (thus) cannot become impure.