# Do the items a Baal Keri touch become impure?

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

So I understand it is said that Ezra's decree no longer applies today. However if one was still Baal Keri would he transfer his tumah to any object (literally any) that he touched?

Say someone had a seminal emission throughout the night. In the morning they wake up and realised what had happened. They have not washed their body, nor immersed in a Mikvah yet.

However, they wash their hands upon awaking. But of course would have to touch things before and after washing such as clean clothes, towel etc... Before that he had to open doors also for example.

So would the Baal Keri have to cleanse everything he came into contact with (not his seed but simply his hands) to achieve a state of taharah for himself and his home? Does anything he touch become tumah or only that which had contact with semen?

Perhaps I am simply over thinking it, any clarity regarding the matter would be greatly appreciated though.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe tumas baal keri is biblical. Ezra just decreed that one could not pray/study before immersion.

Comment: You are quite right, I believe so. Pardon my confusion, I was thinking more of the level of strictness regarding the Mitzvah, rather than the Mitzvah itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rambam in [Hilchot She'ar Avot HaTum'ah 5:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Other_Sources_of_Defilement.5.1?lang=bi) rules that a *ba'al keri* has the status of a *rishon le-tuma'h*.

As such, he would only impart impurity to food or drink which he touches, but not anything else (see [Hilchot Tum'at Met 5:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Defilement_by_a_Corpse.5.7?lang=bi)).